# How to check if a certain element exists using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a html form which I can append using JavaScript, I use PHP to save the data to a JSON file. However, when I click the submit button while there is no form (not appended yet) it still saves data to the JSON file:

```
 [{"language":null,"time_in_words":null,"time_hours":null,"time_mins":null,"audio":null}]
```

Is there a way to check if the form (or a div wrapped around the form) actually exists? (using PHP)

Edit:
Here's my PHP for submitting the form and sending it to the JSON file

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   $_POST = array_filter($_POST);
      if(file_exists('data.json')){
          $current_data = file_get_contents('data.json');
          $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
          $extra = array(
              'language'         =>       $_POST["language"],
              'time_in_words'          =>       $_POST['time_in_words'],
              'time_hours'         =>       $_POST["time_hours"],
              'time_mins'         =>       $_POST["time_mins"],
              'audio'                  =>       $_POST["audio"],
);
            $array_data[] = $extra;
            $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
            if(file_put_contents('data.json', $final_data)) {
              $message = "Successfully saved";
              echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            }
          }
          else
          {
            $error = "data.json does not exist";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$error');</script>";
          }
 }
```

Comment: No, is not possible, unless the `HTML` code is in a `PHP` variable, `PHP` is a serverside language, not clientside.

Comment: You would need to use your js to check before you do whatever with your json

Comment: if the form is not appended yet you would not be getting the values in the request. Right?

Comment: @ParantapParashar Actually the form already exists, the input fields are appended using JavaScript.

Comment: My guess is you're assuming the fields are there without checking the `$_REQUEST` if they are actually there?

Comment: @Barskey yes, that is what I am saying that if input fields do not exist inside the form then you should not get anything in your request.

Comment: @ParantapParashar Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean with my request.

Comment: @Barskey No issues. By request I mean $_REQUEST variable.

Comment: @Barskey Do you hide/show your form's fields using JS or do you add new html for them inside your form every time?

Comment: You are able to check if the submit button parameter is present in $_POST - then you should also be able to check for the other fields the same way, right?

Comment: @ParantapParashar I add/append new inputs using JS, so when I refresh the page there is no input present.

Comment: @Barskey So if there is no input present then in case of no form you can check isset for inputs. Like : `if(isset($_POST["language"])){ \\do some action }`

Comment: @ParantapParashar In my case the language input is required so this will work for me, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ParantapParashar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7198161/parantap-parashar) for helping me figure this out. =)

```
if(isset($_POST["language"])){
  // *submit the form to the json file*
}
else {
  // *tell the user to add an input field*
}
```

This checks if `<input type="text" name="language" required>` has any value. If it doesn't exist, it has no value, so the outcome would be false.

If it does exist, it would still have no value, but since i gave the input element the "required" attribute it wouldn't let the user submit before the user gives it a value (by filling in the input field).

So when the user fills in the input field, the outcome would be true.